# dataprovider excel file reading how skip first row

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

### Heading

```
how to skip first row , if i make i=1 in for loop giving null null for 
 first row values
```

how to skip first row , if i make i=1 in for loop giving null null for

### first row values

```
  how to skip first row , if i make i=1 in for loop giving null null for 
 first row values
   package excel2;

  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.IOException;

               import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
               import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
                import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
               import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
               import org.testng.annotations.Test;

          public class DataProvider2 {
                       XSSFSheet sheet;
                     int row ;
                        int col;

        @Test(dataProvider = "excel")
     public void tc_01(String Srno, String name,String add) {
     System.out.println("name :" + Srno + "\t palce :" + name + "  add : 
           "+add);
               }
             /**
               * @author pritesh
  * @return
  * @throws IOException
  */
  @DataProvider(name = "excel")
    public Object[][] abc() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fl = new 
   FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\pritesh\\Desktop\\x22.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fl);
    sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
    row = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
    col = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    Object[][] obj = new Object[row][col];
    for (int i = 1; i <row; i++) {
        XSSFRow rw = sheet.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) {
            obj[i][j] = rw.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
           }
       }
       return obj;
       }

         }
```

all the row except first row of excel sheet should be read and show in 
console
all the row except first row of excel sheet should be read and show in 
console
all the row except first row of excel sheet should be read and show in

### console

all the row except first row of excel sheet should be read and show in 
console

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below line after first for the loop

`if (i=0){ continue; }`